# Slim + Twig - how to turn off Twig cache during development?

Tags: php, caching, twig, slim

This is the view which is twig that I inject it in the container in Slim:

```
// Views and Templates
// https://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $settings = $container->get('settings');

    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        'cache' => 'cache',
    ));

    // Add twig extension.
    $twig->addExtension(new \Twig_Extensions_Extension_Array());
    return $twig;
};
```

With this setting, Twig always read the template from the cache. Is there any way I can turn off the cache **during the development**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

change "cache" to false. 
Like this

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => false,
));
```