# Always the same view content on slim framework with twig after save changes

Tags: twig, slim, slim-3

I'm using Slim and Twig and I'm trying to change a view content, but it doesn't change after I saved the changes.

This is the controller:

```php
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
require './classes/connection.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('../../views', [
        'cache' => '../../views_cache'
    ]);

    // Instantiate and add Slim specific extension
    $router = $container->get('router');
    $uri = \Slim\Http\Uri::createFromEnvironment(new \Slim\Http\Environment($_SERVER));
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension($router, $uri));

    return $view;
};

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    /*$name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    echo getcwd();

    return $response;*/
    return $this->view->render($response, 'login.html', [
        'name' => $args['name']
    ]);
});

$app->post('/login', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $post_data = $request->getParsedBody();

    if (isset($post_data['user']) && isset($post_data['pass'])) {
        $mongo = new Connection();
        $conn = $mongo->getConnection();
        $collection = $conn->prueba->users;
        $result = $collection->find(['user' => $post_data['user']])->toArray();
        $dbUser = $result[0]['username'];
        $dbPass = $result[0]['password'];

        if (password_verify($post_data['pass'], $dbPass)) {
            echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
        } else {
            echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
        }
    } else {
        return $response->withJson(array('login_status' => 'ko'));
    }
});

$app->run();
```

What I missed to see the view changes? I think it's something about compile view but I'm not sure. It's the first time I use this framework.

Comment: When developing, disabling Twig cache is a good idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584433/slim-twig-how-to-turn-off-twig-cache-during-development

Comment: ^ or set `auto_reload` to true

Comment: As @Nima said, delete contents of `views_cache` and disable Twig cache in development environment.